# calculate missing values, Interpolation

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I've following data:

```
gasprices={{{"Year", "EUR05/GJ"}, {2000., 14.4041}, {2005., 22.8756}, {2010., 
   29.1499}, {2015., 29.4374}, {2020., 30.3778}, {2025., 
   33.2288}, {2030., 35.099}, {2040., 36.8245}, {2050., 38.2697}}}
```

with `ListLinePlot`, I get a nice graphic.

How can I calculate the missing values like for the year `2001`, `2002`, `2003`, `2004`?

I'd like to calculate the interim values.

Any input would help me a lot!!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the [Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) Function:

```
gasprices={{{"Year", "EUR05/GJ"}, {2000., 14.4041}, {2005., 22.8756}, {2010., 29.1499}, {2015., 29.4374}, {2020., 30.3778}, {2025., 33.2288}, {2030., 35.099}, {2040., 36.8245}, {2050., 38.2697}}};
iFunct = Interpolation[gasprices[[1, 2 ;; All]]];
```

This creates a function `iFunct[]`. You can get the interpolated values like this:

```
Map[iFunct, {2001, 2002, 2003, 2004}]
(* {16.0923, 17.8138, 19.5384, 21.2358} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

### Interpolation and Approximation

If you would like to have a functional model *approximating* instead of *interpolating* your data, you can use (besides others) `Fit`:

```
data=gasprices[[1,2;;]]/.{y_,v_}->{Round@y,v};
approx=Fit[data,{1,x,x^2,x^3},x]; (* simple cubic fit *)
interp=Interpolation[data];       (* cubic interpolation *)

With[{min=Min@data[[All,1]],max=Max@data[[All,1]]},
 Plot[{approx,interp[x]},{x,min,max},
  Epilog:>{{Dashed,Gray,Line[{{#[[1]],0},#}]&/@data},
    {PointSize[Large],Red,Point@data}},
  AxesLabel->gasprices[[1,1]],Ticks->{data[[All,1]],Automatic},
  AxesOrigin->{min,0},
  PlotLegends->Placed[{"Approximation","Interpolation"},Below]]]
```

Comparison of both methods:

[image: comparison of cubic approximation and interpolation]

### Discussion

It might be worthwile looking at the extrapolation behavior, too, so the following graph comes from the same `data`, but `min` set to the intersection of the approximating function with the x-axis, and `max` extended 10 years farther into the future than your data tries to predict:

[image: extrapolation behavior for actual data]

In essence, both approaches are more or less questionable in their extrapolation behavior, so: Without a good functional model to fit for, extrapolation might be nonsensical in many cases. In any way, *Mathematica's* extrapolation warning message (issued for `Interpolation` objects when leaving the original domain) should raise your suspicions.

Depending on the data at hand, interpolation can lead to oscillating behavior even between the control points supplied by your data, so I would strongly advise to **never use `Interpolation` without checking the actual behavior!**

---

Hopefully, my utterings were of some assistance to your quest.

Comment: Note that rather than mapping `Point`, i.e., `Point/@data` you can use `Point@data` or equivalently `Point[data]`. These are faster. Although for a small number of points such as in this example the difference is minimal.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Good hint. I will change my code accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

### [TimeSeriesResample](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html?q=TimeSeriesResample)

```
priceseries=gasprices[[1,2;;]];
priceseries[[All,1]] = Rationalize /@ priceseries[[All, 1]];
psinterpolated = TimeSeriesResample[priceseries, 1, 
    ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 2}];

gp = priceseries /. {a_, b_}:> {{a}, b};
ts = psinterpolated /. {a_, b_}:> {{a}, b};
DateListPlot[{gp, ts, ts}, Joined -> {False, False, True},
  PlotStyle->{Directive[PointSize[.03], Opacity[.5], Blue], Red, Green}, 
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotLegends->{"original", "interpolated", "interpolated - joined"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {gp[[All,1]], Automatic}}, 
  GridLines -> {gp[[All, 1]], None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Machine Learning

some vanilla classics:

- Neural Network
- Decision Tree
- Gaussian Process
- Nearest Neighbors

Borrowing the formatting from @kglr 's answer above:

```
gasprices = {{{"Year", "EUR05/GJ"}, {2000., 14.4041}, {2005., 
     22.8756}, {2010., 29.1499}, {2015., 29.4374}, {2020., 
     30.3778}, {2025., 33.2288}, {2030., 35.099}, {2040., 
     36.8245}, {2050., 38.2697}}};
priceseries = gasprices[[1, 2 ;;]];
priceseries[[All, 1]] = Rationalize /@ priceseries[[All, 1]];
gp = priceseries /. {a_, b_} :> {{a}, b};

trainingData = Rule @@@ priceseries;
neuralNet = Predict[trainingData, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
decisionTree = Predict[trainingData, Method -> "DecisionTree"];
gaussianProcess = Predict[trainingData, Method -> "GaussianProcess"];
nearestNeighbors = Predict[trainingData, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"];

nNet = Table[{{year}, neuralNet[year]}, {year, 2000, 2050, 1}];
dTree = Table[{{year}, decisionTree[year]}, {year, 2000, 2050, 1}];
gProcess = Table[{{year}, gaussianProcess[year]}, {year, 2000, 2050, 1}];
nNeighbors = Table[{{year}, nearestNeighbors[year]}, {year, 2000, 2050, 1}];

DateListPlot[{gp, nNet, dTree, gProcess, nNeighbors}, 
  Joined -> {False, True, True, True, True}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[.03], Opacity[.5], Magenta], 
    Green, Blue, Red, Black}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotLegends -> {"original", "NeuralNetwork", "DecisionTree", 
    "GaussianProcess", "NearestNeighbors"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {gp[[All, 1]], Automatic}}, 
  GridLines -> {gp[[All, 1]], None}]
```

[image]